# Proof of transcendence of $\ln (\pi)$

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

From Wikipedia $\ln (\pi) $ is unknown to be transcendental.

$e^{(ie^{(\ln(\pi)})}=-1$

$i(e^{(\ln(\pi)})=i\pi$ is transcendental.

Due to the 
Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem
any transcendental number raised to a power $y$ which yields a non transcendental number implies that $y$ is transcendental or zero

This implies $\ln (\pi)$ is transcedental if I am not mistaken? If not where is my error?

Comment: $e^1$ is transcendental, but $1$ is not.

Comment: You did not show that ln(π) is transcendental , you found that π is transcendental i is algebraic and product of algebraic with algebraic is algebraic so π is transcendental. I am in proving ln(π).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have misunderstood Lindemann-Weierstrass.  Lindemann-Weierstrass (actually Lindemann) says $e^a$ is transcendental when $a$ is nonzero and algebraic.  This is certainly not the case when $e$ is replaced by an arbitrary transcendental number.  For example, $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental and $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic, but $(2^{\sqrt{2}})^\sqrt{2} = 2$ is algebraic.

Comment: when do I take something to a power other then e?

Comment: @shaihorowitz $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$.

Comment: Where are you using Lindemann-Weierstrass in your argument?

Comment: Ah so all this proves is $ie^{(\ln(\pi))}=i*Pi$ is Transcendental, A well know fact.

Comment: @shaihorowitz $\ln x$ is a transcendental function, which implies that it isn't algebraic. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function#Examples

Comment: The fact that $\ln(x)$ is a transcendental function says nothing about what values of $x$ make $\ln(x)$ a transcendental number.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I made an error, as I meant to reply to Wojowu: I'm sorry for any confusion. However, even so, my implication was that not all values of $a$ and $b$ would be accepted by the Lindemann-Weierstrauss theorem in the case of $a^b$